# React: run async operations inside a context provider before it is consumed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, json-server

I'm running a React front-end app and I'm using JSON Server to mock a back-end. I'm also trying to use a Context to mimick the end-points that the front-end app can call.

I'm calling JSON Server endpoint from a useEffect hook inside the context provider component, the same component also uses a reducer to manage the methods exported with the context.

What happens in my code is that when the ViewComponent calls the context's get() method the reducer first **returns its result (which at that point is an empty array) and only after that the DbProvider's useEffect hook loads the data from the mock server**.

I tried to wrap the ViewComponent with a HOC that supposedly should render only if the context value was set, but I never had it render it's inner component.

This is a very far-fetched example, but **I'd like to know if there is a way to run the DbProvider's useEffect hook before components can consume it**, since I already know that it's required from the moment I pass it as a provider in the App component.

--DbContext.js

```
const DbContext = createContext({
    data: [],
    get: () => {},
});

function dbReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case "GET":
            return { ...state, data: action.payload, }
        default: return state;
    }
}

function DbProvider(props) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dbReducer, {data: []});
    const [db, setDb] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios({ method: "get", url: "http://localhost:3001/db", responseType: "json", })
        .then((res) => setDb(res.data));
    }, []);

    function get() {
        dispatch({ type: "GET", payload: db, });
    }

    return (
        <DbContext.Provider value={{ data: state.data, get }}
            {...props}
        />
    );
}

export { DbContext, DbProvider };
```

--App.js--

```
import { DbProvider } from "./DbContext";

export default function App() {

    return (
        <DbProvider>
            ...
        </DbProvider>
    );
}
```

--ViewComponent.js--

```
import { DbContext } from './DbContext';

export default function ViewComponent() {

    const { get } = useContext(DbContext);
    const people = useRef([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        people.current = get();
    }, [])

    return ( ... )
}
```

--ViewWithContext.js--

```
import { DbContext } from './DbContext';
import ViewComponent from './ViewComponent';

export default function FeedWithContext(props) {
    return ( 
        <DbContext.Consumer>
            {dbContext => dbContext.value && <ViewComponent {...props}/>}
        </DbContext.Consumer>
    )
}
```

Comment: Remote API calls are async by nature. They shouldn't block rendering of your app. Your component should always be able to render while the request is still under way. It's best practice to indicate a loading state to the user if you expect noticable loading times. `useEffect` always runs **after** render. There is no way to make it run before that. Using a library like [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) will save you a lot of headaches when dealing with loading, caching, prefetching as those are common problems.

Comment: I'm going to take a look at react-query...